# cascade routers. Cant acces second router configuration

Tags: networking, router

I'm configuring two router to have the same network ir order to access to an arm board throught ssh.

First thing I done is set the main router with ip "172.26.0.1", mask "255.255.255.0" and gateway "172.26.0.1". this router haven't got wifi but internet.

Secondly I configured the other router with static ip "17.26.0.67", mask "255.255.255.0" and gateway "172.26.0.1". Eventually I disabled DHCP on the second router to able the first one to manage the ips.

Till now everything seem to work fine. I'm connected (and writing right now) connecte to wifi with the ip "172.26.0.107" (With WAN config the ip is something like "192.168.0.102"...)

But then When i tried to access throught wifi to the router configuration I only can access to the main router (with ip "172.26.0.1"), and not to the second one (in "172.26.0.67")...

I followed many tutorial but anything works :(... I need to access to the configuration of both routers to change able the NAT and set the port forwarding.

there is a capture of the ip table of the main router: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iccc6er93oycg58/ip_table.png

The second one seem not to exist, but it's transmitting wifi

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the LAN or the WAN IP address on your Wifi router? Which port on the router is connected to the primary router?

Comment: Oh! that was! I thought that i set the LAN addres, but was the WAN.I'm  silly >.<. Now I can connect through ssh and the external ip address! Thanks thanks thanks!